# WPF : Binding error when scrolling a datagrid vertically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I've a binding error when scrolling my datagrid vertically.

My datagrid is defined as follow :

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" IsReadOnly="True" Style="{StaticResource DataGridNormalStyle}" Margin="5,0,5,5" ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredList}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nom" Binding="{Binding Value.Ouvrier.Nom}" Width="210">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding DataContext.AppContext.User.IsConnectedAsDirection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Value="true"/>
                                <!--TODO : Need to fix error-->
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Value.Ouvrier.APEAutre}" Value="APE"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Value.Ouvrier.Profession}" Value="Ouvrier"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00FF00"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Prénom" Binding="{Binding Value.Ouvrier.Prenom}" Width="150"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Matricule" Binding="{Binding Value.Ouvrier.Matricule}" Width="125" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridTextColumnElementCentered}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="N° SAP RH" Binding="{Binding Value.Ouvrier.SAPRH}" Width="100" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridTextColumnElementCentered}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenteredColumnHeaderStyle}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The problematic line is this one :

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding DataContext.AppContext.User.IsConnectedAsDirection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Value="true"/>
```

I'm using MVVM.

Everything works fine, all my binding works correctly. I've no error when I display the view. But when I start scrolling my datagrid vertically, I've a lot of binding failures in the "XAML Binding Failures" window, one by line scrolled :
[image]

Someone told me that this could be caused by the fact the cell go outside of the rendered part and have no longer access to the context.
But I really don't know how to solve that.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: you can ignore them. or try using [BindingProxy](https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) as a workaround

Comment: `RelativeSource` doesn't always work reliable (the binding will fail at first and will be setup later) with datatemples and UI virtualization. You have to use more direct binding in such cases: `ElementName` or proxy (as per @ASh comment). Another approach is to turn virtualization off, but that may impair performance even more than ignoring errors.

Comment: I don't know how many entries do you have, but may be switching off the virtualization of `DataGrid` can help.